# I want to update programmatically the parameter from the Firebase Remote Config

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-remote-config

This is the code that I have:

```
  final FirebaseRemoteConfig config = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();
    config.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
    config.fetch(0).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // After config data is successfully fetched, it must be activated before newly fetched
                // values are returned.
                config.activateFetched();
                    final String playStoreVersionCode = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString(
                            "android_latest_version_code");
            } else {
                Utils.appendLog("playStoreVersionCode Error fetching latest params ", "E", Constants.TIMELINE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now I want to increment my parameter, and I saw that from March there is a REST API in order to update parameters:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/api-overview
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest

But I don't really understand the tutorial. 
Why do I need to use curl? is this really necessary like in the use-config-rest link?

`curl --compressed -D headers -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -X GET https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-id/remoteConfig -o filename`

And the quickstart just shows an example on how to fetch the data, not change it:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/config/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/config/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote Config parameters aren't meant to be changed from client code.  They're only meant to be read on the client.  If you want to change thing programmatically, you're supposed to do that from a server your control.

If you want a read/write some persisted value in your app, don't use Remote Config.  Use Realtime Database or Firestore instead.

The reason for showing curl commands in the documentation is to illustrate how to make the HTTP request using a command that many people are familiar with.  You can make the HTTP request any way you want, as long as you follow the specification.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. There is no way to change the remote Config, from the client code side. Only from a server. Thanks. I will look into Firestore then

Comment: I won't say that there is no way to do this from the client.  It's just not intended to work that way.  If you wanted to make this work, you would have to include project admin credentials into your app, which is a huge security hole.  Remote Config parameters are only meant for consumption in a client.